# Datatable Alpha - Numeric Sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatable

I am using Jquery Datatable in my application. In that, need to achieve alpha- numeric sorting. I tried in many way but unable to achieve. Following is the sorting order(Ascending):

```
current
2H 2016
2H 2016
4Q 2016
2H 2016
1Q 2017
1H 2017
2H 2017
3Q 2017
4Q 2017
2Q 2017
1H 2018
1Q 2018
2Q 2018
Q1 2018
```

I have tried this in following JSFiddle link. This sorting is working fine for unique values. If data has more than one same value (Ex:2H 2016) not listing one by one. That is the issue. Please help me to fix this.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rYtxh/442/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use datatables [natural sorting plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/natural)

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('table').dataTable({
      "aoColumns": [{
        "sType": "natural"
      }],
      "aaSorting": [
        [0, "asc"]
      ],
      'bFilter': false,
      'bInfo': false,
      'bLengthChange': false,
      'bPaginate': false
    });
  });
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://datatables.net/download/build/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.13/sorting/natural.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Timing</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-order="2017 2Q">2Q 2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-order="2017 1Q">1Q 2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-order="2017 1H">1H 2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-order="current">current</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-order="2017 2H">2H 2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-order="2017 3Q">3Q 2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-order="2017 4Q">4Q 2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-order="2018 1H">1H 2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-order="2018 1Q">1Q 2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-order="2016 2H">2H 2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-order="2017 2Q">2Q 2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-order="2018 2Q">2Q 2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-order="2016 4Q">4Q 2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-order="2018 Q1">Q1 2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-order="2016 2H">2H 2016</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.Using natural sorting , years are not sorted. I want both alphabetical and years to be sorted. I have mentioned the required sorting order in my question.

Comment: So basically you ve to swap the alphabetical part with the year... in order to do that use data-order attribute... check my edit